# How does a Micronaut controller determine its base URL

Tags: java, web-services, micronaut

For example if I have the following controller:

```
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;

@Controller("/test")
public class TestController {
    @Get()
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String index() {
        // How should this be implemented?
        return "???";
    }
}
```

and I run it on my-server, then I would like the index method to return http://my-server:8080.

Comment: Would you like to return the hostname and port of the host where the application is running or would you like to return the base url how your API is reachable (e.g. behind a proxy)?

Comment: @saw303 the latter would be preferable, but the former is good enough for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asof Micronaut V1.2.0, you can use the [HttpHostResolver interface](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#hostResolution), for example:

```
import io.micronaut.http.*;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;
import io.micronaut.http.server.util.HttpHostResolver;
import io.micronaut.web.router.RouteBuilder;

@Controller("/test")
public class TestController {
    private final HttpHostResolver httpHostResolver;
    private final RouteBuilder.UriNamingStrategy uriNamingStrategy;

    public TestController(
            HttpHostResolver httpHostResolver,
            RouteBuilder.UriNamingStrategy uriNamingStrategy
    ) {
        this.httpHostResolver = httpHostResolver;
        this.uriNamingStrategy = uriNamingStrategy;
    }

    @Get()
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String index(HttpRequest httpRequest) {
        return httpHostResolver.resolve(httpRequest) +
                uriNamingStrategy.resolveUri(TestController.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;
import io.micronaut.runtime.server.EmbeddedServer;
import io.micronaut.web.router.RouteBuilder;

import java.net.*;

@Controller("/test")
public class TestController {
    protected final String baseUrl;

    public TestController(EmbeddedServer embeddedServer, RouteBuilder.UriNamingStrategy uns)
            throws MalformedURLException {
        final String host = embeddedServer.getHost();
        final int port = embeddedServer.getPort();
        final String file = uns.resolveUri(TestController.class);
        baseUrl = new URL("http", host, port, file).toString();
    }

    @Get()
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String index() {
        return baseUrl;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure whether it's idiomatic, or whether it works in all cases. If someone posts a better answer I'll accept that.

Comment: Do you know which handler is in charge of your annotation @Controller with the given path. This found, i think you can maybe find how the whole url is constructed get it back ?

Comment: You can eliminate a good bit of that by calling `embeddedServer.getURL()` instead of calling `getHost()`, `getPort()` etc. and piecing it together by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Just discovered `HttpHostResolver` in 1.2.0, which seems to be a more idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the controller to respond at `/` then use `@Controller("/")` instead of `@Controller("/test")`.

Comment: Not sure how this relates to my question.

Comment: You said " then I would like the index method to return http://my-server:8080" and I thought that meant you wanted the index method to be executed when you sent a request to `http://my-server:8080`.

Comment: I see now.  I understand the question.  I misunderstood initially.  I apologize for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.tech.api;

import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.PathVariable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Controller("/")
public class ModelDefinitionsApi {

    @Get(uri="/modelName", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getModel(@PathVariable String modelName) {
        return "modelName";
    }
}
```

http://my-server:8080 => main controller url

http://my-server:8080/modelName => for getModel method